# service fabric, control what events get saved to table storage

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-table-storage

I have a service fabric cluster on Azure and it has a very simple app running on it. The app is from [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-create-your-first-application-in-visual-studio/).

When running the app locally, the Visual Studio Diagnostic Events shows 3 events.

- CRM
- MasterCRM
- ServiceMessage

I believe the CRM and MasterCRM are related to the cluster manager and the ServiceMessage shows events from my app, in this case just a message saying the current value of a counter.

This data is also saved in a table storage, I was wondering is there any way for me to control what gets saved to the table storage? Right now my table consists of pages and pages of CRM and MasterCRM messages and I've yet to see messages from my app, I'm sure if I keep going I might eventually see it, but so far no luck.

I'd like to just save the events from my app to the table storage and ignore the rest. I've looked around and found no way to do it.

Comment: how about if you application publish the events that you need to save to a queue, then have a process pick up the events and save them to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events you refer to are coming from ETW from the fabric runtime (CRM, MasterCRM) and your application (ServiceMessage) like you mentioned.  The diagnostics viewer in Visual Studio is getting these events directly from ETW and not Azure Table Storage.  If you want to filter the events showing up in the diagnostics viewer you can click the gear icon and edit the sources listed.

*CRM comes from Microsoft-ServiceFabric:5:0x4000000000000000.

Controlling what events get uploaded to Azure Table Storage in an Azure hosted cluster would require editing the ARM template's diagnostics section similarly.

Comment: Yup, Turns out I had to edit the template file and add in my EventSource. I followed steps from this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad/